# iOS Video Caching - Manual cache deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, caching

I have a React Native application which uses [React Native Video with iOS caching](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/docs/caching.md). I have been working on a method inside [RCTVideoCache.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m) which would manually delete the data of a particular cache key. According to the documentation of SPTPersistentCache, which the video library uses for caching, data can be deleted either by [locking/unlocking a file](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache#lockingunlocking-files) and [invoking a wipe](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache#manually-managing-cache-usage) or after inspecting the source code of `SPTPersistentCache.h` with a method named [removeDataForKeys](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache/blob/master/include/SPTPersistentCache/SPTPersistentCacheImplementation.h#L188).

I have tried both ways, however, unsuccessfully.

In **my first try**, I am using [wipeLockedFiles](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache#manually-managing-cache-usage). I have created a `deleteFromCache()` method inside [RCTVideoCache.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m). Since all my video files are unlocked by default, in this method I am trying to lock the file corresponding to my `cacheKey` and [invoke a wipe](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache#manually-managing-cache-usage) on all locked files (which would consist of only my target `cacheKey` file) as it is demonstrated in the documentation. This method looks like:

```
- (void)deleteFromCache:(NSString *)cacheKey withCallback:(void(^)(BOOL))handler;
{
  [self.videoCache lockDataForKeys:@[cacheKey] callback:nil queue:nil];
  [self.videoCache wipeLockedFiles];
  NSLog(@"Size = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes));
  handler(YES);
}
```

The following results in two errors during compilation:

```
/Users/.../MyApp/node_modules/react-native-video/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m:79:20: error: no visible @interface for 'SPTPersistentCache' declares the selector 'lockDataForKeys:callback:queue:'
  [self.videoCache lockDataForKeys:@[cacheKey] callback:nil queue:nil];
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../MyApp/node_modules/react-native-video/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m:80:20: error: no visible @interface for 'SPTPersistentCache' declares the selector 'wipeLockedFiles'
  [self.videoCache wipeLockedFiles];
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I really have no idea why these selectors are not visible from `SPTPersistentCache`.

In **my second try**, I am using [removeDataForKeys()](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache/blob/master/include/SPTPersistentCache/SPTPersistentCacheImplementation.h#L188). Again, I have created a `deleteFromCache()` method inside [RCTVideoCache.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m) which looks like this:

```
- (void)deleteFromCache:(NSString *)cacheKey withCallback:(void(^)(BOOL))handler;
{
  [self.videoCache removeDataForKeys:@[cacheKey] callback:^(SPTPersistentCacheResponse * _Nonnull response) {
    NSLog(@"Result output: %@", response.output);
    NSLog(@"Error output: %@", [response.error localizedDescription]);
   } onQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
  NSLog(@"Size = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes));
  handler(YES);
}
```

In this second way, there are no errors, however, the data of the key is never deleted. Also, both `NSLog`s for the response output `null` inside the terminal.

I am 100% sure that the `cacheKey` I am providing to my `deleteFromCache()` method is correct and data corresponding to it exists. However, in both methods `NSLog(@"Size = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes));` does not change and I can also manually verify that the file has not been deleted.

I am really stuck and do not know what is wrong with the code I've written in both cases and why neither of them works. I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Can you please share the entire RCTVideoCache.m, modified version? Maybe as a GitHub gist.

Comment: is this errant code? `} onQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];` - i cant see what it belongs to in you second example

Comment: @ivanmoskalev I haven't modified anything else in the original [RCTVideoCache.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m). I have only added the method provided above — `deleteFromCache`.

Comment: @ewizard This is some code I used to satisfy the parameters of `removeDataForKeys()`. I saw that the same method is used in [other parts of RCTVideoCache.m](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/VideoCaching/RCTVideoCache.m#L73)(line `73`).

Comment: oh yah i see it now thanks for clarifying

Comment: @IamOptimus still, please share it. Obj-C's syntax is easy to get wrong in small details, and it seems that this is exactly the case here.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev I have just uploaded it: https://gist.github.com/iAmOptimus/767342f4eba52e5bff0f0027ee5423ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all sub-folder's files `(tmp/rct.video.cache)`, iterating each one:

```
+ (void)deleteFromCache
{
    NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.temporaryCachePath error:NULL];

    for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.temporaryCachePath, file] error:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I added a `/` in `stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@"` and the files are deleted successfully!

Comment: @IamOptimus Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran your example and discovered that you are using incorrect method signatures. These methods simply don't exist in the caching library, their signatures [are different](https://github.com/spotify/SPTPersistentCache/blob/master/include/SPTPersistentCache/SPTPersistentCacheImplementation.h#L188).

Try something like this:

```
 - (void)deleteFromCache:(NSString *)cacheKey withCallback:(void(^)(BOOL))handler;
 {
     NSLog(@"Size before = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes));

     [self.videoCache lockDataForKeys:@[cacheKey] callback:nil onQueue:nil];
     [self.videoCache wipeLockedFilesWithCallback:^(SPTPersistentCacheResponse * _Nonnull response) {
         NSLog(@"Size after = %@, response = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes), response);
         // Call handler after the files are wiped
         handler(YES);
     } onQueue:nil];
 }
```

I have no idea why the second approach doesn't work, but `NSLog(@"Size = %@", @(self.videoCache.totalUsedSizeInBytes));` is for sure called before the actual deletion happens. In the example I posted above, I have moved the logging statement into the callback closure, so that it reports the size before and after the deletion takes place.

Comment: I have just tried this. Inside the terminal, I can see the cache size updating properly after the deletion and the response message stating that the operation has completed successfully. However, the files are still cached. React Native Video still locates the file inside the cache and plays it without downloading. Using [Filza](https://cydia-app.com/filza/) I can verify the videos are still inside the `tmp/rct.video.cache` folder of the application. Do you have any idea why this method does not delete the video data files?